# Почему возвращается неправильный %errorlevel%?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

Я использую такую старенькую утилитку [time-mem](https://code.google.com/p/time-windows/) для измерения времени выполнения какой-то команды из командной строки. Это просто проект на с++, основной код [здесь](http://pastebin.com/5gSUR0WA).

Начинаю проверять, для теста запускаю *timemem 7z some-err-str*.
Понятно выводится ошибка, показывает код 7, возвращается этот код.
Но в батнике, если сразу за этой командой вывести *echo %errorlevel%*, получаю 0.

Сам батник:

```
timemem 7z some-err-str
rem timemem возвращает 7. А выводится на экран 0
echo %errorlevel%
```

В общем ведёт себя также, как похожая утилита ptime.

Почему, у меня нет объяснения. И главное, как можно исправить?

Comment: Вопрос не конкретный. Выглядит как "разберитесь для меня с программой"..   Я думаю, это вам самому надо сделать.

Comment: Да, ошибка была глупая. Сейчас шапку поправлю.

Comment: Только я не знаю, как закрыть вопрос или принять его.

Comment: А вообще я не понимаю, как можно даже в такой маленькой программе сделать ошибку...

Comment: @YShinkarev: Вы не могли бы перенести решение из вопроса в ответ? (И в ответе стоит написать, откуда взялось `info`, а то так непонятно.)

Comment: Момент. Я просто помню, что у меня был случай, когда я ответил на свой же вопрос (просто на so), меня там поправили и сказали, что лучше напишите в шапке солюшен...

Comment: @YShinkarev: Насколько я понимаю, сейчас предпочитаемый паттерн — явный ответ. Например, чтобы можно было дать альтернативный ответ и другим проголосовать за него.

Comment: > Момент. Я просто помню, что у меня был случай, когда я ответил на свой же вопрос (просто на so), меня там поправили и сказали, что лучше напишите в шапке солюшен. - у меня тоже часто такая ерунда: не знаешь, куда лучше написать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в ерунде. В c++ [коде](http://pastebin.com/5gSUR0WA) функция *info()* всегда возвращала 0. А именно результат этой функции определяет код возврата программы.
Поменял в самом конце info()

```
return 0;
```

на

```
return dwExitCode;
```

Стало правильно. Сбивало ещё что, в консоль выводился правильный код возврата, а реально возвращался 0.